# How to block all Dynamic URLs except 1 category

Tags: url, dynamic, block, robots.txt

I have a website :
Right now we have lots of dynamic pages http://www.canvaschamp.com/

I want to block all dynamic URLs except Flower Canvas prints Category (http://www.canvaschamp.com/photo-gallery/flowers)

Let me know your suggestions that how to block all product pages except Flower Category in **ROBOTS.TXT** or any other way....

Thanks

Comment: When you say block, you mean you don't want search engines to index these pages?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disallow everything and exclude /photo-gallery/flowers, there is as far as I know no `Allow:`, neither are there wildcards (like `*`).

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /dir1/
Disallow: /dir2/
Disallow: /photo-gallery/dir1
Disallow: /photo-gallery/dir2
```